# Using the $n$-roots of unity to do the reduction modulo $n$

Tags: roots, integers

In particular, I want to generalize the following fact:

For any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, we can write

$\frac{1-(-1)^x}{2}=x \mod 2$

Is it possible to do similarly for any $n\geq 2$? Where we have a function $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that

$f(x)=x \mod n$

and that f is written in terms of the $n$-roots of unity?

Comment: I think that the analogue is this. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. ($\exp\frac{2\pi i}{n}$ if you will.) Then $\frac{1}{n}(1^k+\zeta^k+\zeta^{2k}\dots+\zeta^{(n-1)k})$ is $1$ when $k$ is a mulltiple of $n$ and $0$ otherwise.  See Discrete Fourier Transform.

Comment: This is very helpful, but doesn't fully answer my question

Comment: It allows you to deal with the function $g_0(k)$ which is $1$ exactly when $k=0\mod n$ and $0$ otherwise. It is easily tweaked to give the function $g_r(k)$ which is $1$ exactly when $k=r\mod n$ and $0$ otherwise.  Now linearity will let you build any function $g(k)$ which is constant on residue classes mod $n$. Isn't that what you want?